# Return "Enter text" if there's no row. (Illegal mix of collations)

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I'm trying to use Coalesce for those entry that doesn't have any rows

I got this to work

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(t1.it, d.it_norow)

FROM (SELECT 0 as it_norow
        FROM DUAL) as d
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT t1.itemText as it
        FROM bullet_items as t1
        WHERE t1.cst_name = 'Cust'
        AND t1.bullet_id = 'BD1') as t1
        ON 1 = 1
```

But when I changed the '0' in the dual table

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(t1.it, d.it_norow)

FROM (SELECT 'Enter text' as it_norow
        FROM DUAL) as d
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT t1.itemText as it
        FROM bullet_items as t1
        WHERE t1.cst_name = 'Cust'
        AND t1.bullet_id = 'BD1') as t1
        ON 1 = 1
```

I get the error `Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'coalesce'`

How can I make it the 'Enter text' work when there's no row?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem by providing a [*`Fiddle Demo`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer, to fix your query:

```
  SELECT _latin1'Enter text'
         ^^^^^^^
```

(That's assuming the  characterset of the `bullet_items.itemText` is latin1, and the characterset of your client is UTF8.)

There's some other syntax, but they all achieve essentially the same thing... that makes the `it_norrow` column (in the derived table) have a latin1 characterset.

There's a much longer explanation (about characterset of the database column, the characterset of the client, and the semantics of conversions between the characterset, the CAST and CONVERT functions, et al.)